# Why is e.touches[] faster in Chrome when Inspector is open?

Tags: javascript, canvas, inspector, ctx

I have a site (live on https://digitaalwisbordje.nl/84734059348524305/Stackoverflow/ ) where a user could write in a <canvas>.
In Chrome and on Chromebook, the drawing works fine with the mouse.

With touchscreen it doesnt... it's way to slow to draw a circle fast.
...
Until you open Inspector (F12 in Chrome). Then all works well.

Why is it faster when Inspector is opened?
And how go to get always that fast respons? This is my main goal now!
Best test is to draw a circle very fast using touch.

```
function findxy_touch(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            console.log(e.touches);
            currX = e.touches["0"].clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.touches["0"].clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                //console.log(prevX);

                // pak touch en muis!
                currX = e.touches["0"].clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                currY = e.touches["0"].clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                draw();
            }
        }
```

Comment: _With touchscreen it doesnt... it's way to slow to draw a circle fast_; Can't reproduce, trying on Google Chrome Mobile browser, works just as fast as on desktop. Could you please add some more information/debugging details?

Comment: Of course, download a Chrome-performance-profile here to view it:
https://digitaalwisbordje.nl/stackoverflow/profile.json

It seems that there arent enough e.touches[] are given thru when Inspector isnt open

Comment: And a small 'discovery' ... the "Touchlist" in the Inspector is diferent when Inspector is (or not is)  opened.
See https://digitaalwisbordje.nl/stackoverflow/picture.png 

First Touchlist the inner 'circle' without Inspector opened: seems like buffer is full?
Second Touchlist is the outer circle with Inspector opened: better or no buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Just by using the code of https://zipso.net/a-simple-touchscreen-sketchpad-using-javascript-and-html5/ (and that links to https://zipso.net/sketchpad/sketchpad-lines.txt) I made it working. With this new code the touch-events are handled better and faster and thus got it working.

My first code shouldnt be used, use the working one instead.